# Fabric TwitterKit compose tweet with image from asset folder

Tags: android, twitter

I am using Fabric in my Android app to compose tweets and I need to include an image.  The `TweetComposer.Builder` class has an `image()` method that takes a Uri object.  I am trying to use an image that exists in the assets directory of my app, but I keep getting an error `couldn't load the image`.

here is my code:

```
File myImageFile = new File("file:///android_asset/image/test_icon.png");
Uri myImageUri = Uri.fromFile(myImageFile);

TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
     .text("test")
     .image(myImageUri);

builder.show();
```

In the debugger I have confirmed that the Uri was successfully created, yet it still fails to load the image.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put image in SDcards because **.image(URI uri)** method just pass url to offical app of **Twitter** and Twitter app find image in SDcard by using provided url.

Comment: You're right, had to copy the image from assets to externalStorageDirectory (Don't forget to add the permission!!). What a PITA. Thanks Sunil!

Comment: It should be in external memory. Fabric can't access image from app.